# Estimating graviton background temperature

Tags: cosmology, entropy, quantum-gravity

I want to estimate the the graviton temperature at $T=1$MeV assuming that the gravitons decoupled at $T \sim m_\text{pl}$, the Planck mass.

My reasoning was the following. We know that due to conservation of entropy that $g_S(T)T^3a^3$ is constant, where $g_S(T)$ is the effective number of degrees of freedom in entropy. From the famous graph on the effective number of relativistic degrees of freedom in cosmology, we have that before the graviton decouples, we have $g_S(T \sim m_\text{pl} ) = 106.75 +2$ and at $T = 1 \text{MeV}$ $g_S(T = 1 \text{MeV}) = 10.75$.

As a result we obtain $$108.75T^3_G a^3_G = 10.75 T^3 a^3.$$

How do I proceed from here?

I'm tempted to use $T \propto a^{-1}$, but this does seem to hold always I believe.

Comment: This can be interesting: [How much uncertainty has the relic graviton background?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/392730/226902). I do not think that it's a black body spectrum with a defined temperature (as it is for the CMB, that it's almost a perfect black body). See also (possible duplicates): [Cosmic gravitational background and its temperature](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/356605/226902), [Is there a Cosmic Gravitational Background Radiation?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/235858/226902).

Comment: Note: I say that it's not a "gravitational black body" because probably gravitons had no time to reach thermal equilibrium in the early universe. However, If the gravitational perturbations had been in equilibrium with other fields, the expected black body spectrum of the gravitational wave background can be found in Fig 1 of [The stochastic gravity-wave background: sources and detection by B. Allen](https://arxiv.org/abs/gr-qc/9604033).

Comment: Thanks for the links! I'm just trying to get an estimate of the temperature here, struggling with the calculation. It seems like today it should be just under 1 Kelvin, but that's not what I'm looking for